# mrdivide function in MATLAB: what is it doing, and how can I do it in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, linear-algebra

I have this line of MATLAB code:

```
a/b
```

I am using these inputs:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]   
b = ones(25, 18)
```

This is the result (a 1x25 matrix):

```
[5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

What is MATLAB doing? I am trying to duplicate this behavior in Python, and the `mrdivide` documentation in MATLAB was unhelpful. Where does the 5 come from, and why are the rest of the values 0?

I have tried this with other inputs and receive similar results, usually just a different first element and zeros filling the remainder of the matrix. In Python when I use `linalg.lstsq(b.T,a.T)`, all of the values in the first matrix returned (i.e. not the singular one) are 0.2. I have already tried right division in Python and it gives something completely off with the wrong dimensions.

I understand what a least square approximation is, I just need to know what `mrdivide` is doing.

#### Related:

- [Array division- translating from MATLAB to Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001634/array-division-translating-from-matlab-to-python)

Answer (score 13):

[MRDIVIDE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html) or the `/` operator actually solves the `xb = a` linear system, as opposed to [MLDIVIDE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) or the `\` operator which will solve the system `bx = a`.

To solve a system `xb = a` with a non-symmetric, non-invertible matrix `b`, you can either rely on `mridivide()`, which is done via factorization of `b` with Gauss elimination, or `pinv()`, which is done via Singular Value Decomposition, and zero-ing of the singular values below a (default) tolerance level.

Here is the difference (for the case of `mldivide`): [What is the difference between PINV and MLDIVIDE when I solve A*x=b?](https://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-3TPS3Y/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-3TPS3Y)

> When the system is overdetermined, both algorithms provide the
>   same answer. When the system is underdetermined, PINV will return the
>   solution x, that has the minimum norm (min NORM(x)). MLDIVIDE will
>   pick the solution with least number of non-zero elements.

In your example:

```
% solve xb = a
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
b = ones(25, 18);
```

the system is underdetermined, and the two different solutions will be:

```
x1 = a/b; % MRDIVIDE: sparsest solution (min L0 norm) 
x2 = a*pinv(b); % PINV: minimum norm solution (min L2)

>> x1 = a/b
Warning: Rank deficient, rank = 1,  tol = 2.3551e-014.
ans =

    5.0000 0 0 ... 0 

>> x2 = a*pinv(b)
ans =

    0.2 0.2 0.2 ... 0.2
```

In both cases the approximation error of `xb-a` is non-negligible (non-exact solution) and the same, i.e. `norm(x1*b-a)` and `norm(x2*b-a)` will return the same result.

**What is MATLAB doing?**

A great break-down of the algorithms (and checks on properties) invoked by the '\' operator, depending upon the structure of matrix `b` is given in this post in  [scicomp.stackexchange.com](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1004/4014). I am assuming similar options apply for the `/` operator.

For your example, MATLAB is most probably doing a Gaussian elimination, giving the sparsest solution amongst a infinitude (that's where the 5 comes from).

**What is Python doing?**

Python, in `linalg.lstsq` uses pseudo-inverse/SVD, as demonstrated above (that's why you get a vector of 0.2's). In effect, the following will both give you the same result as MATLAB's `pinv()`:

```
from numpy import *

a = array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
b = ones((25, 18))

# xb = a: solve b.T x.T = a.T instead 
x2 = linalg.lstsq(b.T, a.T)[0]
x2 = dot(a, linalg.pinv(b))
```

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR: `A/B = np.linalg.solve(B.conj().T, A.conj().T).conj().T`

I did not find the earlier answers to create a satisfactory substitute, so I dug into Matlab's reference documents for mrdivide further and found the solution. I cannot explain the actual mathematics here or take credit for coming up with the answer. I'm just following Matlab's explanation. Additionally, I wanted to post the actual detail from Matlab to give credit. If it's a copyright issue, someone tell me and I'll remove the actual text.

```
%/   Slash or right matrix divide.
%   A/B is the matrix division of B into A, which is roughly the
%   same as A*INV(B) , except it is computed in a different way.
%   More precisely, A/B = (B'\A')'. See MLDIVIDE for details.
%
%   C = MRDIVIDE(A,B) is called for the syntax 'A / B' when A or B is an
%   object.
%
%   See also MLDIVIDE, RDIVIDE, LDIVIDE.

%   Copyright 1984-2005 The MathWorks, Inc.
```

Note that the `'` symbol indicates the complex conjugate transpose. In python using numpy, that requires .conj().T chained together.

Comment: As an explanation, we are trying to solve `XA = B` for `X`. Computing the transpose of both sides yields `A'X' = B'`. Since `np.linalg.solve` solves `CY = D` for `Y`, then we can let `C = A'` and `D = B'` to get `Y = X'`. Finally, we get `X` back by transposing `Y`.

Answer (score 1):

a/b finds the least square solution to the system of linear equations bx = a

if b is invertible, this is a*inv(b), but if it isn't, the it is the x which minimises norm(bx-a)

You can read more about least squares on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares).

according to [matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/mldivide.html), mrdivide will return at most k non-zero values, where k is the computed rank of b. my guess is that matlab in your case solves the least squares problem given by replacing b by b(:1) (which has the same rank). In this case the moore-penrose inverse `b2 = b(1,:); inv(b2*b2')*b2*a'` is defined and gives the same answer

Comment: I realize that. Do you have an answer to the question?

Comment: note that b is rank deficient (rank 1) and matlab remarks on this.

Comment: ok, do you know of a way to do this in python? and did you test your idea with actual code?

Comment: `numpy.linalg.pinv()` compute Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of a matrix

Comment: This is wrong. `bx = a` is solved in MATLAB with `x = b\a`, which is not the same as `x = a/b`. What `a/b` does is solve the linear system `xb = a`.

Answer (score 1):

Per [this handy "cheat sheet"](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html) of numpy for matlab users, `linalg.lstsq(b,a)` -- `linalg` is [numpy.linalg.linalg](http://www.scipy.org/doc/numpy_api_docs/numpy.linalg.linalg.html), a light-weight version of the full `scipy.linalg`.

Comment: I can't get linag.lstsq to give the same answer as the matlab lstsq algorithm.  Perhaps they work differently.