# Solve linear equation in python XA = B

Tags: python, numpy, inverse

A linear equation `XA = B`, we know the 'X = B * inv(A)'. where `A, B, X` are all matrix.

in the matlab it can be solve:

```
X = B / A
```

it avoid doing inverse a matrix which is [fast](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inv.html). is there any equal form in python using numpy?

Comment: Can't you just do `x = b * 1/a`? Or am I just really bad at this

Comment: sorry for the confusion, they are all matrix, I will update them

Comment: I am afraid there is no such function in numpy. see http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html.

Comment: Good resource, is there any way we can solve `XA = B` in python?

Comment: Have you seen [this related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007442/mrdivide-function-in-matlab-what-is-it-doing-and-how-can-i-do-it-in-python)?

Comment: I see, It is duplicate. thanks all your helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use numpy linalg.inv function:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.matmul(b, np.linalg.inv(a))
```

Comment: cool. it has same result as matlab.

Comment: @jason it may give the same answer, but it will take a lot longer due to inverting `a` if `a` is large.  Look into using `np.linalg.solve(a, b)` (or `np.linalg.lstsq(a, b)` if `a` is not linearly independent) instead.  These do a similar short circuit to `MATLAB` without doing the full inverse.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,7],[2,9]])
b = np.array([[2,6],[7,5]])

# XA = B
# X = BA^-1

x = np.matmul(b,np.linalg.inv(a))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.