# Matlab matrix division into python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

I'm so confused with the right division in matlab.

```
m = [1 2 3 4 ; 5 6 7 8]
x = m/sum(m)

x = 
0.2907
0.7093
```

I don't know how matlab gets this result, obviously x * sum(m) is not equal to m, and how to do this in python?

Comment: Find your solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1001727/3768871

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not using the [element-wise division](https://mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/rdivide.html), the operation you are performing equals to solving `xA = B` for `x` where `A = m` and `B = m_sum` (see [mrdivide](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html)):

```
m = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8];
m_sum = sum(m);
x = m / m_sum;
```

which can also be written as:

```
m = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8];
m_sum = sum(m);
x = mrdivide(m,m_sum);
```

The `Python` equivalent, using the `Numpy` library, would be:

```
import numpy as np

m = np.matrix('1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8')
m_sum = np.sum(m, axis=0)
x = np.dot(m, np.linalg.pinv(m_sum))
```